# htaccess apending parked domains subfolder to the URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I created a website for a client and as per normal with our sites included an htaccess file to redirect any non-www traffic to the www. subdomain.

The client has now added a parked domain as a subfolder where they want to host another site. If you go to `www.parkeddomain.com` then it works, displaying the site in the PARKEDDOMAIN.COM subfolder. However if you go to `parkeddomain.com` then the htaccess redirects you to `www.parkeddomain.com/PARKEDDOMAIN.COM`. How can I stop it appending the subfolder to the URL?

This is the contents of the htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect old URLs to new URLs
Redirect /jewelry-the-experience /custom-made-jewelry
Redirect /jewelry-the-process /custom-made-jewelry

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)$ /handle-url.php [L]
```

Comment: `If you go to www.parkeddomain.com then it works, displaying the site in the PARKEDDOMAIN.COM subfolder`. How is it possible? I don't see any rule in your htaccess forwarding `parkeddomain.com` to a subfolder. Is it your entire code ?

Comment: Because you park the domain using the control panel for the hosting, and in there you tell it what folder the parked domain looks at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following rule just before the existing one.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^parkeddomain\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:parkeddomain\.com/?)?(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|parkeddomain)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

We catch the no-www parked domain first and redirect without its sub-directory. This makes sure the existing rule is always redirecting the primary domain only.

Comment: Made no difference, it still redirected to `http://www.parkeddomain.com/PARKEDDOMAIN.COM`

Comment: @Styphon Test it again in a different browser. 301 [R]s are cached by the browsers.

Comment: I cleared my cache before trying, always do. Just to be sure I tried a different browser now and it's done the same thing.